# How can I create code for specific variable?

Tags: fortran, nested-loops, fortran95, do-loops

I want to embed a code for Fortran 95.

For example: I have read an integer variable

```
   read *, x
```

for instance x=4. and my source creates four loop which has four loop variable

```
   loop1:do a=1,16
   loop2:do b=1,16
   loop3:do c=1,16
   loop4:do d=1,16
   ........smt......
   end do loop4
   end do loop3
   end do loop2
   end do loop1
```

I'm working on a such a code that tries for finding a magic square. I can find a magic code by using a algorithm for odd numbered square matrices. probably, I also can generate a magic square which is even numbered and double-even numbered. however , I'm trying to improve my coding skills by writing a program that tries element by element to find magic square.

```
implicit integer (a-z)
```

> counte=possibility counter , magcon=magic square generated counter
>   god and devil are logical variables. But I used them as integer.

```
    integer GG(3,3),COUNTE,magcon
    integer god,devil
   open(55,file='mymagics')
   COUNTE=0
    magcon=0


 loop1:do a=9,1,-1
    loop2:do b=9,1,-1
    loop3:do c=9,1,-1
    loop4:do d=9,1,-1
    loop5:do e=9,1,-1
    loop6:do f=9,1,-1
    loop7:do g=9,1,-1
    loop8:do h=9,1,-1
    loop9:do i=9,1,-1
```

> these loops are for evaluating elements

```
    GG(1,1)=a
    GG(1,2)=b
    GG(1,3)=c
    GG(2,1)=d
    GG(2,2)=e
    GG(2,3)=f
    GG(3,1)=g
    GG(3,2)=h
    GG(3,3)=i
    call elementcontrol(gg,devil)
    if(devil.eq.1)then
    call magiccontrol(GG,god)

    else if(devil.eq.0) then

        cycle



    endif
    COUNTE=COUNTE+1


if(allah.eq.1) then
magcon=magcon+1
write(55,66)
   write(55,*) counte ,"possibility is tried"
   write(55,*)"**************************************"
     write(55,*)"**************************************"
       write(55,*)"**************************************"
   write(55,*)"--------------------------------------"
write(55,*)GG(1,1),GG(1,2),GG(1,3)
write(55,*)GG(2,1),GG(2,2),GG(2,3)
write(55,*)GG(3,1),GG(3,2),GG(3,3)
write(55,*)"--------------------------------------"
  write(55,*)"**************************************"
    write(55,*)"**************************************"
      write(55,*)"**************************************"

write(55,66)
66 format(//)




else

    print *, counte ,"possibility is unvalid"

    end if
enddo loop9
enddo loop8
enddo loop7
enddo loop6
enddo loop5
enddo loop4
enddo loop3
enddo loop2
enddo loop1
print *, "finally done!"
print *, magcon,"magic square is found"
stop

end


subroutine magiccontrol(magic,logic)







integer logic,z
integer magic(3,3),sumrow(3),sumcol(3),sumdia(2)
```

> these are row,column and diagonal sum finder

```
 do z=1,3
    sumrow(z)=0
    sumcol(z)=0
    sumdia(z)=0
    end do
do 31 k=1,3
do 31 l=1,3
    sumrow(k)=sumrow(k)+(magic(k,l))
    31 continue



 do 52 m=1,3
    do 52 n=1,3
        sumcol(m)=sumcol(m)+(magic(n,m))
        52 continue


        do 69 i=1,3

        sumdia(1)=sumdia(1)+magic(i,i)
        sumdia(2)=sumdia(2)+magic((4-i),i)



    69 continue

    loop1:do y=1,3

    loop2:do f=1,3

     loop3:do x=1,2

    if(sumrow(y).eq.15) then
       if(sumcol(f).eq.15)then
        if(sumdia(x).eq.15)then
    logic=1
    else
        logic=0
        exit loop1
  end if
        else
            logic=0
            exit loop1
    end if
       else
        logic=0

        exit loop1
    end if
end do loop3
end do loop2
end do loop1
```

> 15 is magic constant. loops are for evaluate whether a aquare is magic or not.

```
end
subroutine elementcontrol(elecon,logic2)

integer elecon(3,3),a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,coun(9)
do a4=1,9
    coun(a4)=0
end do
logic2=0
do a1=1,9
    do a2=1,3
        do a3=1,3
            if(a1.eq.elecon(a2,a3))then
                coun(a1)=coun(a1)+1
            end if
        end do
    end do
end do
do a5=1,9
 do a6=1,9
      if(a5.ne.a6) then
    if(coun(a5).eq.coun(a6)) then
        logic2=1
        else
            logic2=0
            exit
    end if
    else
        cycle
        end if
end do
end do
```

> there loops are to evaluate whether every element is different from each other or not.

end

Now the problem is that if I will be inclined to increase number of rows and columns of magic square, I have to rewrite element specifier loops. But I'm not willing to that. So I want to declare a variable,read it , and be able to make program create do loops as read.
I wish I was crystal clear about what I want to know.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get some attention. No-one follows just the tag for the specific 95 version.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense to me. Please show us more code explain exactly what is happening.

Comment: One component of your question seems to be *How can I read an integer `m` at run-time and create an `m`-deep nest of loops ?*  To that question the answer is, you can't.  But neither constructing an `m*m` magic square, nor checking that a given square is magic, requires that approach you should probably select a different algorithm.

Comment: I see you have elected to use implicit typing (ie `implicit integer (a-z)`).  If you have a gun to hand first replace that line of code with `implicit none`, then take off one shoe and one sock (no point in getting holes in those) and shoot yourself in the bare foot.  This will result in less pain than using implicit typing.  If you have no gun, then a 10kg steel weight dropped from your hand will probably suffice.

Comment: Actually you can have an arbitrary depth nested loop, sort of, but not directly. For this I have in the past defined an iterator type which just held the m values, and an update method. Then simply an unbounded Do loop with calling the update method and some special way to indicate termination and you are sorted. Admittedly I never properly implemented Exit and Cycle for name loops, but it's pretty straightforward to code up at least for the simple case. If I find time and the poster adapts his code to Implicit None I may post this.

Comment: I will be very grateful if you make this Ian Bush

Comment: Thanks for your advice High Performance Mark

Comment: Arbitrarily nested do loops were already treated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344707/n-nested-for-loops-in-fortran90

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks, that's the essence of what I'm saying, I'm just hiding the gory implementation details a bit ( and allowing code reuse ).

Comment: To get the effect of arbitrarily-nested loops, use recursion instead. For the recursive case, start a new loop that, on each iteration, calls the recursive function to do the more-inner loops. For the base case, do what's inside the most-inner loop.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Can you explain more detailed as you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

The test could look something like this:

```
LOGICAL FUNCTION IsMagical(dim_o_square, SquareData)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER                                    , INTENT(IN   ) :: Dim_o_Square 
REAL, DIMENSION(Dim_o_Square, Dim_o_Square), INTENT(IN   ) :: SquareData

REAL, DIMENSION(Dim_o_Square)                              :: Row_Sum, Col_Sum
REAL                                                       :: Diag_Sum

IsMagical = .FALSE.
INTEGER                                                    :: I 

IF(Dim_o_Square < 2) THEN
  WRITE(*,*) '[SubMagic?:line10]  DIMENSION of square is hosed'
  RETURN
ENDIF

!   Fill the data to determine PFM'ness
DIAG = 0
DO I = 1, Dim_o_Square
  COL_Sum(I) = SUM(SquareData(:,I))
  ROW_Sum(I) = SUM(SquareData(I,:))
  DIAG_Sum   = Diag + SquareData(I,I)
ENDDO

!   Test for PFM'ness
DO I = 2, Dim_o_Square
  IF( COL(I) /= Diag .OR. ROW(I) /= Diag ) THEN
    RETURN
  ENDIF
ENDDO

!Must be magical at this point...
IsMagical = .TRUE.
WRITE(*,*) '[SubMagic?:line40]  Magical and sum value (Row/Col/Diag)=', DIAG_Sum

RETURN
END FUNCTION IsMagical
```

Perhaps there is some carry over in concepts for producing the square?